# Magento 1 How Customer allowed to do a partial payment?

Tags: magento-1.9, authorize.net

This is the first time when customer completed an order with partial payment using Authorize.net payment method. I can see the 'Total Due' row in the order totals box.

**Allow Partial Authorization** is set to no.

What could have allowed customer to pay partial amount?

Comment: What is the full magento 1.9.x version, and do are all the latest patches in place? If all is up to date with no custom payment code I would contact Authorize.net to see if there's any data they can provide to see if it was circumvented.